# Safari overwriting email and password fields on an edit user form

Tags: html, autocomplete, safari, passwords, autofill

I have an edit-user form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" />
  Email:
   <input type="text" name="email" value="user@domain.com" />
  Password:
   <input type="password" name="password" value="thesavedpassword" />
</form>
```

Safari overwrites my pre-filled username and password for me, so I added all the autocomplete options - this didn't work.

Reading on here, I hear that readonly has worked for some, so I tried that too, but that still doesn't work. Here is what the code looks like with all that in:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" autocomplete="off" />
  Email:
   <input type="text" name="email" value="user@domain.com"
      autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
  Password:
   <input type="password" name="password" value="thesavedpassword"
      readonly autocomplete="off" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
</form>
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here! Why would Safari overwrite fields that are already filled in?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The password management engine will kick in as soon as it detects a password field and once it has, it will look for the nearest text field before the password field and assume that one to be a username field.

The autocomplete attribute is ignored by most browsers but I have read that setting it to "false" rather than "off" has worked for some (not me).

There is no clean solution to this. The only thing that has worked for me is to introduce hidden dummy fields for safari to populate.